# Google ndb -- how to do range queries on 2 (or more) attributes

Tags: google-maps, app-engine-ndb

I have a table with [Event | LAT | LONG | time ... etc.].  Given a lat-&-long values, I would like to fetch all events that fall within a certain range of the lat/long (say roughly 5 miles around it).  In SQL, I would probably do something like:

```
SELECT * WHERE LAT > lat+5 and LAT < lat-5
           AND LONG > long+5 and LONG < long-5.
```

Can I do something similar in google's ndb database ? I see a filter query on one single attribute given as example:

```
qry = Account.query(Account.userid >= 40, Account.userid < 50)
```

But it doesn't seem to allow more than one attribute.

regards
GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a restriction of the Datastore (not just NDB) that you can't do this.  You may try to use geohashing, or if you don't have much data, just do a range query on one dimension and filter the other dimension using Python code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Guido. We are currently doing that -- filter on one dimension first and then loop through results to filter on another dimension. From 50,000 data points, getting the resultant 10 or 20 points is taking 20-30 seconds. That's crazy slow!  Disappointing that ndb does not have multi-attribute search.  I could do this in Sqlite in milliseconds. We will look into this geohashing. Thanks.

Comment: Repeat after me: *it is not an NDB issue*. The underlying *Datastore* does not support 2-dimensional queries.  (NB is just a client library; Datastore is the storage server.) Anyway, when you say it takes 20-30 seconds, how many points did you actually load into memory there? You could play around with batch size to see if it can be tuned.